# no response on stdout HackerRank Swift

Tags: swift

Hello i practice on hackerRank using swift and now i have a problem. My code works great in swift playground, and return the expected result, but in HackerRank i have runtime error  `~ no response on stdout ~` I've tried to reset code and refresh page. What could be the problem?

```
func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]]) -> Int {
    // Write your code here
   let rowNumber = arr[0][0]

    var leftD = 0
    var rightD = 0

    for i in 1...rowNumber {
        leftD += arr[i][i - 1]
    }

    var increasedNum = 0

    for i in (1...rowNumber).reversed() {
        rightD += arr[i][increasedNum]

        increasedNum += 1
    }

    var absoluteDifference = leftD - rightD

    if absoluteDifference < 0 {
        absoluteDifference = absoluteDifference * -1
    }

    return absoluteDifference
}
```

Here is the challenge page:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem

Comment: Your problem is a misunderstanding of what is passed to your diagonalDifference() function.  The code which calls that function uses the first line of input to correctly size the array, but that value IS NOT passed to your function in arr[0][0].  Instead, you should use `arr.count` to determine the size of the array, then you should be indexing the array as `0..<arr.count`.

Comment: Thanks i understand now. Can you write this in answers, because it's solved my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of what is passed to your `diagonalDifference()` function. The code which calls that function uses the first line of input to correctly size the array, but that value **is not** passed to your function in `arr[0][0]`. Instead, you should use `arr.count` to determine the dimensions of the array, then you should be indexing the array as `0..<arr.count`.

To fix your code

change:

```
let rowNumber = arr[0][0]
```

to:

```
let rowNumber = arr.count
```

change:

```
leftD += arr[i][i - 1]
```

to:

```
leftD += arr[i][i]
```

And change both instances of

```
1...rowNumber
```

to:

```
0..<rowNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]]) -> Int {

  var difference = 0
  for i in 0..<arr.count {
    difference += (arr[i][i] - arr[i][arr.count-1-i])
  }
  return Int(abs(difference))
}
```

Comment: It's work thanks, but why my code doesn't work ? I know my code isn't good but it return the correct result.

Comment: @Eduard - see [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007). This is an attempt to answer the question and should **not** be deleted.

Comment: @Wa Ha Lee - The answer (while correct or not), solution wise, does not contain any information as to what’s wrong with the OP’s version, nor does it explain why it works while the OP’s doesn’t and so on. All that aside, there’s no option for SO in triaging, regarding “requiring an edit” or more insight yet, as well as it being a community process (meaning there needs to be a general consensus over one’s decision in order for it to be put in action ). So even if one is wrong, or not, subject of the triage is still fine. Regards!